# Refactoring If Statements

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have to create a grading system for my C# programming assessment and I'm currently trying to refactor redundant code.

```
foreach (Student item in mark)
{
    if (ComboBoxGradeMethod.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        item.Grade = vetMethod.VETGrade(item.Mark);
    }
    else if (ComboBoxGradeMethod.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        item.Grade = newVETMethod.VETGrade(item.Mark);
    }
    else if (ComboBoxGradeMethod.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        item.Grade = gradeMethod.CollegeGrade(item.Mark);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a grading scheme.");
    }
}
```

Here in this 'for each' loop are 3 if statements. A friend of mine said I can reduce the code by creating a method and passing a function as a parameter.

I'm a beginner programmer and what he said is a bit beyond me at the moment.
I was wondering how I would go about doing it?
I don't want the entire answer, just how to go about doing it.

Comment: It is a matter of style whether or not you move it to a method. But, he would be describing something like: `public void AssignGrade(Student item) { }`. This method would contain everything except the `foreach`. Then you would rewrite the foreach to be: `foreach (Student item in mark) { AssignGrade(item); }`. I'm not convinced it's a large improvement, unless your current method is large.

Comment: You should probably move the `if` statement outside of the loop. Currently you will get a lot of message boxes if you don't select a grading scheme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `item.Mark` is an `int` and `item.Grade` is a `string` then this is how I would do it:

```
var gradeFromMarkMethods = new Dictionary<int, Func<int, string>>()
{
    { 0, vetMethod.VETGrade },
    { 1, newVETMethod.VETGrade },
    { 2, gradeMethod.CollegeGrade },
};

Func<int, string> gradeFromMark;
if (gradeFromMarkMethods.TryGetValue(ComboBoxGradeMethod.SelectedIndex, out gradeFromMark))
{
    foreach (Student item in mark)
    {
        item.Grade = gradeFromMark(item.Mark);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a grading scheme.");
}
```

Comment: @Tyress - Thank you. I'm glad you think so.

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions.

1. Try using `switch case` instead of `if - else`.
2. Create a `function` for Assignment of Grade
3. Try to separate `UI controls` from the code, you can get the value of the variable from UI controls like `ComboBoxGradeMethod` and then pass it to the function. The `UI` may change in future, so it is better to decouple the business logic from `UI`.